# split excel cell using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, split

GIVEN: Using VBScript, I am trying to rearrange the way data is presented in an excel document. I know that the data will always be in the following format:

```
       A      |               B              |  C  |  D  
--------------|------------------------------|-----|-----
1 ANGLE       | 6 x 3-1/2 x 5-16 x 240       |  1  | C1054
2 SQAURE TUBE | 1-1/2 x 1-1/2 x 1/8 x 31-3/4 |  3  | C1588
3 DOM TUBE    | 5-1/2 OD x 1" WALL           |  4  | C1670
```

GOAL: My goal is to get it into this format:

```
                 A                |    B    |  C  |   D
----------------------------------|---------|-----|-------
1 6 X 3-1/2 X 5-16 ANGLE          | 240     |  1  | C1054
2 1-1/2 X 1-1/2 X 1/8 SQAURE TUBE | 31-3/4  |  3  | C1588
3 5-1/2 OD X 1" WALL DOM TUBE     |         |  4  | C1670
```

My idea is to first insert blank columns between columns B and C. Then, I will use the split command to break up column B with little "x" where this intermediate step will look like:

```
       A      |     B    |    C    |   D  |    E   | F |  G    
--------------|----------|---------|------|--------|---|-------
1 ANGLE       | 6        | 3-1/2   | 5-16 | 240    | 1 | C1054
2 SQAURE TUBE | 1-1/2    | 1-1/2   | 1/8  | 31-3/4 | 3 | C1588
3 DOM TUBE    | 5-1/2 OD | 1" WALL |      |        | 4 | C1670
```

Next I will take and move column A to be between columns D and E. Then I will somehow mash the numbers together using " X " and then mash that column with the next to reach the goal.

My code in vbscript is:

```
'inserting 3 blank columns into given format
objSheet2.Columns("C:C").Insert xlToRight
objSheet2.Columns("C:C").Insert xlToRight
objSheet2.Columns("C:C").Insert xlToRight
'splitting
Split objSheet2.Columns("B:B"),"x"
'objSheet2.Columns("B:B").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
'        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
'        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
'        :="x", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2)), _
'        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'moving column A between column E and F
objSheet2.Columns("A:A").Cut
objSheet2.Columns("F:F").Insert
```

I first recorded a macro and just pasted it into my vbscript all willy nilly and that obviously didn't work, that's why I have it commented out. The split command isn't working either. I'm getting a Type Mismatch error at the start of the Split line during the run. Note, in row 3 there is one less piece of information than the other lines have.

QUESTION: How do I arrive at my goal format from my given format using VBScript and possibly a split command?

Comment: You don't make your goal very clear. Are you saying that if there are 3 "x" in the string, split it, put the last value in the column it was originally in and move the remainder to the middle of the string in column A.

Comment: splitting cell B1 "6 x 3-1/2 x 5-16 x 240" would yield B1="6 " B2="3-1/2 " B3="5-16" and B4="240"

Comment: That's not what you show as your goal.

Comment: i mistyped that. Splitting cell B1 "6 x 3-1/2 x 5-16 x 240" would yield B1="6 " C1="3-1/2 " D1="5-16" and E1="240" The next step after splitting will be rearranging the cells in order to match the goal order. The last step will be joining cells.

Comment: It is easiest to explain what your end goal is, not the steps you want to take. Oftentimes folks have better ways to achieve the same result, but asking about how to do the steps you think are correct muddies what you are really asking. We want to avoid an [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting the whole column, you can just check how many " x " are in the cell value and update the cell values in column A and B accordingly

```
For Each cell In objSheet2.UsedRange.Resize(, 1)     ' column A
    a = Split( cell.Offset(0, 1).Value , " x ", 4 )  ' the cell in column B
    If UBound(a) > 2 Then                            ' if more than 2 " x "
        cell.Value = a(0) & " X " & a(1) & " X " & a(2) & " " & cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "'" & a(3)
    Else
        cell.Value = Replace( cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, " x ", " X " ) & " " & cell.Value
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If
Next
```

Comment: in the second line of code ...., " x ", .... I changed it to "x" because there are cases where no spaces exist. I didn't say that in the question so my bad on that one. This seems to have done the trick to get everything the way I needed it. Thank you.

Comment: @john yeah I tried to be safer in case there is `x` in any of the column B words. If you split by "x", some space adjustments or Trim() will be needed for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach a bit differently.
Working with VBA arrays is usually faster than doing a lot of worksheet stuff

- Read the source data into a 2D vba array
- Using a Regular Expression, process the second column to remove the last item if and only if it matches the regex pattern below.
- Concatenate the "shortened" measurement with the description from Source column one, and put this into results column 1.
- Remove the 'x' and spaces from the captured last item of the measurement and put that into results column 2.
- Copy original columns three and four into the results array.
- Write the results array to a new worksheet, and do some formatting. (One could, by merely change the results worksheet, overwrite the original data).

This seems to work as you describe on your posted data:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReFormat()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

'set worksheets for source and results
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read source data into variant array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
End With

'create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'Initialize Regex
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "\s+x\s+(\d[-./\d]*\d\b)\s*(?!.*x)"
End With

'Cycle through the rows
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    vRes(I, 1) = Trim(RE.Replace(vSrc(I, 2), "")) & "  " & vSrc(I, 1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        If MC.Count = 1 Then vRes(I, 2) = MC(0).submatches(0)
    vRes(I, 3) = vSrc(I, 3)
    vRes(I, 4) = vSrc(I, 4)
Next I

'write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Columns(2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

And the Regex Pattern description:

```
\s+x\s+(\d[-./\d]*\d\b)\s*(?!.*x)
```

- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the character “x” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `x`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d[-./\d]*\d\b)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
  - [Match a single character present in the list below](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[-./\d]*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
    - [A single character from the list “-./”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-./`
    - [A “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
  - [Assert position at a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!.*x)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the character “x” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `x`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: While this might be a good solution, I specifically asked for vbscript. It was a good lesson in VBA as I have never used Regex before.

Comment: @john Sorry about that.  VBscript is a subset of VBA, and I didn't realize it did not support the regular expressions dll